# Forcing https for the codeigniter project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want my whole site under https. So I did two things:

1.I changed my base_url in the config.php to

```
https://localhost/codeignitor.
```

from

```
http://localhost/codeignitor.
```

2.My changed .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|codeignitor|include|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [QSA]

# The following two lines newly added

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off # To redirect all the http to https

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

But when I visit

```
http://localhost/codeignitor/mysite
```

this is my error [Though it get redirected to https]

```
Not Found

The requested URL /codeignitor/my_site was not found on this server.
```

But

```
https://localhost/codeignitor/index.php/my_site
```

is woking fine.

Comment: I saw a potential typo at "codegnitor"

Comment: Thanks, actually it is codeignitor. I edited it.

Comment: I think it's possible that your server config for https is not setup correctly, can you check if your .htaccess file is read when you're using https?

Comment: Does a static file load under https on localhost? Like an image or text file outside of Codeigniter?

Comment: you´re using XAMPP or a similar bundle installer? you run multiple sites under the same CI installation?

Comment: ^Daniel, How to do that? Actually now I find that https://localhost/codegnitor/index.php/my_site is working. But not https://localhost/codegnitor/my_site

Comment: I am using LAMP. No, I am not accessing any file outside Codeignitor. No, only a single site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems .htaccess is not read in your https server config and you're using LAMP (Apache) so please go to your server config location for https, e.g. default-ssl or httpd-ssl.conf, and make sure AllowOverride is turned on. If you don't the line, you will need to add that.

```
<Directory /your/directory/to/codeigniter/>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I got it working after adding this line and restarting the apache ;). Thank you.